# Add Style to text in a PHP block

Tags: shortcode

I have created a slider in header.php, which has a title and a log-in form. I would like to style the title.

```
<div class="half"><?php echo 'Sign Up for New Membership'. do_shortcode( "[mepr-membership-registration-form id=702]" );// NEW REGISTRATION FORM ?> </div>

<div class="half"><?php echo 'Returning member? Sign In!'. do_shortcode( "[mepr-login-form]" );// LOGIN FORM ?></div>
```

I have tried the following. Nothing broke, but it did not style the title.

```
 <div class="half">
    <?php echo "<span class='h2'>".'Sign Up for New Membership'."</span>"; echo do_shortcode( "[mepr-membership-registration-form id=702]" );// NEW REGISTRATION FORM ?> </div>

<div class="half"><?php echo 'Returning member? Sign In!'. do_shortcode( "[mepr-login-form]" );// LOGIN FORM ?></div>
```

I'm new to PHP and would love any help on what needs editing in the snippet above. Thanks so much!

Comment: Unless you have CSS styles for the class `.h2` you're not actually adding any styling here. It really depends on whether you want to use styles that are already in your theme (in which case you need to look through their CSS and see what classes will accomplish what you want it to look like) or if you are trying to add your own CSS. If you are editing `header.php` that should mean you have a child theme so you can add the CSS there.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks so much. Oddly, I have already been using a styled H1-H3 on the rest of the site. Just made a new class just for this title and it worked! I hate making new classes for every little thing, so i was trying to be economical. :/

Comment: It is good to consolidate, it just looked like perhaps you were trying to target an `<h2>` whereas you have a `<span>` with a class `"h2"` and those are different. You can always add a comma in your CSS to style two things the same way - i.e. `h2, .h2 { font-size:2em; }` - if your markup differs.